# Find a set datatype key present in redis

Tags: redis

I need to check whether a key of datatype set is present or not. How to find it? Any property in Redis? Checked in redis commands, but didn't find any. Please help.

Example : sadd("Uid132423","Apple");

Need to check whether "Uid132423" exists. Please help.

Comment: Hello, sorry the question is not very clear, could you rephrase it more clearly? Thanks.

Comment: Use the [type](http://redis.io/commands/type) command. If it returns set, you know it exists. If it returns None, well, it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have to use SCARD. It returns 0 if key does not exist.